# Pruning miniature olive trees

Tags: pruning

I have a small Cailletier olive tree that I hoping to keep indoors. I live in New England so it cannot be outdoors in the winter.

It is currently getting somewhat long and sprawling in its branches which are like fronds.

Should I try to make it more bushy if it is to become an indoor plant? If so, what is the pruning method for doing this?